# JS - Efficiently sort alphabetically using Collater.compare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I need to sort Arabic strings on the front end, and give each string an index. So the JSON is an array of objects of course, and each object has an Arabic string property. I can use

```
comparer = new Intl.Collator("ar")
a = "ا";
b= "ب"
comparer.compare(a,b);
```

where "ar" is the arabic language flag, and the a and b variables ar the arabic equivalents. comparer function as used returns -1, saying 'a' comes before 'b'. other values are 0 if they're equal and 1 if the first parameter comes alphabetically after the second.

so how do i iterate over the array of objects to sort the objects alphabetically?

Comment: Can't you just use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): `[b, a].sort(comparer)`

Comment: wow. yes that does work.